# Why is wiretapping called "bugging" and since when?

Tags: etymology, slang

For eight years, Trump *bugged* (annoyed) Obama with questions about his birth certificate.  Later, Trump claimed that Obama *bugged* (wiretapped) him.

Merriam-Webster offers this "legal" definition of "bug," but gives no etymology:

> to plant a concealed microphone in — compare *eavesdrop*, *wiretap*

It's been used this way as both a verb and a noun:

> Trump wiretapping claim: Did Obama **bug** his successor?

- [The *BBC*](http://Trump%20wiretapping%20claim:%20Did%20Obama%20bug%20his%20successor?)

> The reason the Administration insisted on "secure and controlled conditions" for reconstruction was because the **bugs** were planted into the walls of the embassy by Soviet Government construction workers.

- [*The New York Times*](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/06/20/world/deal-made-on-bugged-us-moscow-embassy.html)

[A search on etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bug) for "bug" says the use in the sense of "wiretapping" dates to 1919, but I can't find a reference to exactly how or why the meaning originated.

Given how frequently the topic of "wiretapping" has been in the news in the U.S., how did wiretapping come to be called "bugging?"

Comment: I hate to break this to you, but Etymonline does mention the wiretapping sense [*Sense of "equip with a concealed microphone" is from 1919.*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bugged) But someone might find an earlier reference, it has happened before. Still...1919 is really early!

Comment: Ngram only finds references back to about 1960.  Wire tapping goes back to the Eliot Ness era, certainly, but it may well be that "bugging", being more complicated technically, didn't come along until around 1960.

Comment: @Mari-LouA woops.  Thanks, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA is there a way with etymonline to find the cited source at that date?

Comment: It's usually the OED, I don't have access to it unfortunately.

Comment: Related: [Origin of “bug” in reference to software](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/origin-of-bug-in-reference-to-software) and [Is the use of the term “bugged” to refer to software bugs in English a worldwide or regional use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325985/is-the-use-of-the-term-bugged-to-refer-to-software-bugs-in-english-a-worldwide)

Comment: Interesting answer by Sven Yarg, EL&U's number one etymologist guy: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/239280/44619

Comment: @Mari-LouA The earliest I'm seeing in OED for this sense of *bug* is from 1936: "The dictaphones (later called ‘dicks’ or ‘bugs’ by the force) were ordered." from *Fighting Underworld*.

Comment: According to ["How Stuff Works"](http://people.howstuffworks.com/wiretapping3.htm), wiretapping has been in existence almost as long as the telephone has been around (1890s). Whether it was called _bugging_ or not is not mentioned; however, it is said that the telephone recording device was already in use by this time, and the US Supreme Court had approved it by 1928.

Comment: @Cascabel surely wiretapping predates the telephone.  The electric telegraph was well established decades earlier.

Comment: @phoog I would have to think about that, but I think the nature of the signal would not allow for interception without degrading it. It is a DC signal in  a closed loop and interupting it would probably block it. Phone signals are analog, and can be intercepted with a bridge or even a simple condensor. And the recording equipment did not come into existence until the late 1800s, AFAIK.

Comment: @Cascabel and electromagnetic telegraphs are so sensitive that the degradation would be detected?  I think not.  You could wire your detecting device into the circuit in series if necessary.  I also can't imagine why you would think recording equipment other than a pencil and paper would be necessary to intercept a telegraph transmission.  A quick web search indeed reveals that wiretapping was prevalent during the Civil war.

Comment: @phoog Yes , I also  found some information that would suggest it was done at least as early as 1845. My point is that DC signals have issues with voltage drops over distance, and hacked-in devices would increase that. Also, it is easier to use encoding with telegraph.

Comment: @Cascabel even *your own link* begins by noting the existence of anti-wiretapping statutes in the 1860s, so actually you paraphrased it inaccurately.  Surely nobody would have bothered with such statutes unless people were actually intercepting telegraph communications.  I guess you didn't read it very carefully.  But the source also reveals its questionable quality by claiming that these statutes were enacted by state courts.  That's not how things work in the US, except perhaps in Massachusetts and New Hampshire, where the legislature is called the "General Court."

Comment: @phoog Whatever. I am done with this.

Comment: Tip for next time, wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer to give others, who are on different times zones, a crack at answering the question. It also increases the chances that everyone's post earn more attention, which equals more votes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's good advice, thanks.  As much as I like the accepted answer, I didn't realize there would be so much more interest.

Comment: The U.S. Embassy in Moscow was bugged with the Great Seal bug in 1945.

Comment: Speaking of insects, I suspect there is some link between this bug and the idiom _a fly on the wall_. No evidence though; if anything, my searches seem to suggest that _a fly on the wall_ came later. Oh well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Bug*, meaning "to arm something with an alarm" is from 1919 and this sense is mentioned as the forerunner of the word *bug*, meaning "to attach or install a listening device". Thus, it is *not* exactly true that the origin of the word *bug*, *bugging* in the sense asked in the original post is from 1919.

It is  mentioned in the book [*20th century words*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=p0h5AAAAIAAJ&q=bug+microphone+1919&dq=bug+microphone+1919&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW3pnym9DTAhWs1IMKHUltDGYQ6AEIODAE) (by John Ayto):
[image]

Here is the excerpt from 1919, from the [*original source*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=YmFIAAAAYAAJ&q=%22the+possibilities+of+the+joint+being+bugged%22&dq=%22the+possibilities+of+the+joint+being+bugged%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY7YKVntDTAhXm6IMKHeuoDKsQ6AEILDAC):[image]

The earliest origin is mentioned as 1935 in the books *20th century words* (by John Ayto) and [*Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary: Eleventh Edition*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=TAnheeIPcAEC&pg=PA162&dq=bug+microphone+1935&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-uOjQptDTAhVh0oMKHUpYCG8Q6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=bug%20microphone%201935&f=false) but I couldn't find the actual reference.

In *OED*, the earliest reference is from 1936 for the noun and 1955 for the verb.

Comment: Huh, I had always assumed `bug` originated because the hidden microphones were about the size of a bug (I have a vague memory of some movie showing a spy microphone this size being clipped onto someone's shirt)

Answer (score -4):

A bug is a small insect (specifically a certain order of small insects) a small hidden microphone is the size of a small insect - at least in the movie going public imagination

Comment: Yes, but a lot of things are the size of a small insect and we don't call them all bugs.  Otherwise I ate some bugs earlier today.

Comment: yes - probably also the context of being hidden and unwanted

Comment: Guesses are no good here.  We need references.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime also bacteria and virii are *much* smaller than insects but when they cause upset digestion (or worse), we *do* call them bugs!

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Well ... it's possible that you *did* eat some bugs earlier today and didn't notice.

Comment: Insects are an order of bugs, not the other way around. Either way this doesn't answer the question.